# Asp.net C# variable & value calculation

Tags: c#, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

```
double a =(80/100);
lbl1.Text = a.ToString();
```

answer is display as 0 why ?
how to get correct answer?

Comment: Why not user decimal instead of double?

Answer (score 5):

the expression `(80/100)` evaluates to 0 because `80` and `100` are both interpreted as `int`, and `int` divided by `int` always results in an `int`.  What you need is this:

```
double a =(80d/100d); 
lbl1.Text = a.ToString();
```

That way the expression uses `double` values and you get what you expect - `0.8`.

Comment: FYI `double a = (80 / 100d)`; also works, as well as `double a = (80 / (double)100);`